# handling multiple database connections using session factories with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java

I have an Spring+Hibernate/Flex application that needs to switch dynamically between database schemas. To accomplish that I implemented a AbstractRoutingDataSource following [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) article. Unfortunately to change between dataSource's doesn't work. 
Someone could help me?

I followed this link:  [Spring + Hibernate SessionFactory + AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378883/spring-hibernate-sessionfactory-abstractroutingdatasource)

My code is:
- ApplicationContext:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${jdbc.url2}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${jdbc.username2}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password2}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="routingDS" class="br.com.cpb.gtf.infra.RoutingDataSource">
   <property name="targetDataSources">
      <map key-type="java.lang.String">
         <entry key="br.com.cpb.gtf.infra.SchemaConstants.TESTE" value-ref="dataSource2"/>
         <entry key="br.com.cpb.gtf.infra.SchemaConstants.PRODUCAO" value-ref="dataSource"/>             
      </map>
   </property>
   <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
</bean>



<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.cpb.*" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true '1', false '0'" </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

-RoutingDataSource:

```
package br.com.cpb.gtf.infra;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey()
    {
        return Globals.getSchema();
    }

}
```

-SchemaConstants

```
package br.com.cpb.gtf.infra;

public class SchemaConstants {

    public static final String PRODUCAO = "dataSource";
    public static final String TESTE = "dataSource2";

}
```

-Globals:

```
package br.com.cpb.gtf.infra;

public class Globals {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> schemaHolder = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static void setSchema(String schema) {
        schemaHolder.set(schema);
    }

    public static String getSchema() {
        return schemaHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearCustomerType() {
        schemaHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

-Service:

```
@RemotingInclude
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public Adm_Usuario logar(Adm_Usuario user)  {

    Globals.clearCustomerType();
    Globals.setSchema(SchemaConstants.TESTE);


    Adm_UsuarioDao dao = new Adm_UsuarioDao(sessionFactory);
    Adm_Usuario admUsuario  = dao.logar(user);      

    setLoggedUserOnSession(admUsuario); 
    return admUsuario;

}
```

Comment: Have you read the answer to the question you refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
```

in property dataSource, ref should be routingDS:

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="routingDS" />
```